# xhtml code "float: right" and "clear: right" is not working

Tags: xhtml, css-float

The image file is floating to the right ok.  It is the paragraph with a span style with a "clear: right" attribute that is not clearing the image.  The text is appearing before the margin to the right is clear of an element, in this case an image.

Here is the all the code that is between the body tags.  The file has the xml prolog,has a DTD that is using xhtml transitional, the opening  tag includes an xmlns attribute that specifies the HTML namespace.

```
<h1 style="text-align: center">Tourist Attractions</h1>

<hr />

<p>
<img src="images/child.jpg" alt="child" style="border: 5px ridge orange; 
float: right" />
<span style="font-weight: bold; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans serif; 
color: darkblue">

The City of Desert Park has many opportunities for fun, recreation, and 
entertainment. Throughout every month, you will find activities for all ages 
and lifestyles. The weather in Desert Park is conducive to outdoor 
activities year-round.

</span>
</p>
<p><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: darkblue; 
clear: right">

Visit the Parks and Recreation Page for the latest information on the 
Basketball League Play-off Games.

</span>
</p>
```

It is the second paragraph that is not clearing the image to the right.  I know a "clear" attribute only clears a preceding element.  But the image is before the "clear" tag.  I just can't figure out why it is not clearing.  It has been a few years since I last used xhtml.  I know that html5 is the thing but the DTD is pointing to xhtml transitional so it should still work.

Can someone tell me why the second paragraph is not clearing the image to the right? I probably have been thinking about this too much and the answer is right in front of me.  Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

The [clear](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#propdef-clear) property only applies to block level elements. Span elements are, by default, inline level and you are not changing that. Move the `clear:right` to the span's containing p element, and the clear will take effect.

This is not specific to XHTML 1.0 Transitional. HTML5 would be exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you.  I did as suggested and it works.  This is coming back now.  Can't have a "span" attribute containing a "clear" attribute in an in-line element because other stuff outside of the "span" would not be marked to clear the float element and just wouldn't work.  A "clear" attribute needs to be block so everything clears.  The funny thing is I have done xhtml years ago.  My niece is learning from my old xhtml book (the only one she has) and that code is from that book.  The code entered above is in the book.  I checked and re-checked.  So there is incorrect code in an instruction book.

Comment: @NDNCode - There's a comment in the CSS2 spec that in CSS1, clear was defined to applied to all elements, not just block level ones. It's unlikely that many implementations in browsers ever followed the CSS1 rule, but it's understandable that an old book might repeat the information from the CSS1 spec.